# JavaScript: GIF file loses animation

Tags: javascript, css, animated-gif

I am trying to set a hidden layer (containing animated GIFs) visible. Initially, the layer is hidden using

```
display: none;
```

However, when I try to show the layer using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('loading_layer').style.display = 'block';
```

the layer is displayed, but the images inside it are no longer animated. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats an Internet Explorer bug. One workaround is:

```
document.getElementById('loading_layer').innerHTML = document.getElementById('loading_layer').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Don't I need to set the display to 'block' first?